# Android. sqlite update last inserte row

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to update the last inserted row, but I get an error:

> 08-20 12:08:23.091: E/AndroidRuntime(13598): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "ORDER": syntax error
>   (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE REVIEW SET json=? WHERE  ORDER BY
>   date DESC LIMIT 1

My code:

```
public int updateDataJSON(Review review) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_JSON, review.getJson());

    return db.update(TABLE_REVIEW, values, " ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1", null);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read the last date in a separate step:

```
db.update(..., "date = (SELECT max(date) FROM ReviewTable)", ...);
```

(If there are multiple rows with the same `date` value, this will update all of them.)

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER BY` and such are only valid in `SELECT` queries, not `UPDATE`s.

Consider the following:

1. Store the last inserted row id as returned by a call to `insert()`:

   ```
   long lastInsertRowId = db.insert(...);
   ```
2. Use the rowid in the update like

   ```
   db.update(TABLE_REVIEW, values, "ROWID=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(lastInsertRowId)2 });
   ```